# NSMutable Array in other class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I declared an NSMutableArray in my .h and I set property and synthesize, but if i want use this array in other class? How I do?

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted some code.

Comment: NSMutableArray *client;  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *client;    @synthesize client;    and I use this array in this mode:     client = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)returnArray];      where returnArray is another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have, as you stated, created an `@property` for the `NSMutableArray`, you can easily access it in other classes by name. For example:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

...

MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array = [myClass.myArray mutableCopy];
```

(Note: I did not use memory management.)

Comment: I don' understand...if I use property and synthesize the name of my array should be visible in other classes, no?

Comment: That is correct. My code sample was showing how to access that array from another class.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea here is that in your original class, the array is referred to by a pointer. Your original class would allocate it and presumably load it. Other parts of your program can be handed the contents of the property, which is a pointer, assign that to their own pointer holder, and use it as if you had declared it there.

So if MyClass has a property of MyArray, which is an NSMutableArry *, then MyArray is a pointer holder, (just 'pointer' for short).

You program can then make a new pointer, like NSMutableArray *ThatArray, and then simply do:

```
MyClass *aClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithMyInitStuff];
NSMutableArray *ThatArray = aClass.MyArray;

NSLog("Count of ThatArray: %d", [That.Array count]);
```